# Selecting specific rows by date in a multi-dimensional df Python

Tags: pandas, python-datetime

[image of df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpFem.png)

I would like to select a specific date e.g 2020-07-07 and get the Adj Cls and ExMA for each of the symbols. I'm new in Python and I tried using df.loc['xy'],  (xy being a specific date on the datetime) and keep getting a KeyError. Any insight is greatly appreciated.
Info on the df MultiIndex: 30 entries, (SNAP, 2020-07-06 00:00:00) to (YUM, 2020-07-10 00:00:00)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
dtypes: float64(2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.xs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html?highlight=xs#pandas.DataFrame.xs) for this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(8).reshape(4, 2), index=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3]], columns=list("ab")
)
print(df)
#      a  b
# 0 2  0  1
#   3  2  3
# 1 2  4  5
#   3  6  7
print(df.xs(3, level=1).filter(["a"]))
#    a
# 0  2
# 1  6
```